# How to compute distance between two affine poses?

Tags: rotations, affine-geometry

If we have two poses in affine space with this parameters: tx ty tz qx qy qz qw,

Where:

tx ty tz (3 floats) give the position of the optical center of the color camera in meters with respect to the world origin as defined by the motion capture system. and qx qy qz qw (4 floats) give the orientation of the optical center of the color camera in form of a unit quaternion with respect to the world origin as defined by the motion capture system.

Is it possibel to compute the distance between this two poses?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "distance between two poses" is not something defined. (Well, you can compute the Euclidean distance between the tuples seen as vectors, but this makes little sense.)

A better option is probably to choose significant points in the camera model (such as image corners), to apply the transforms and compute the total distance between corresponding points.